# opengl won't render desired output after switching from glTranslatef to gluLookAt

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet

I have trouble to get `gluLookAt` working. I have the following code which works as expected using `glTranslatef`:

```
import pyglet 
from pyglet.gl import *

window = pyglet.window.Window() 

def draw_square():
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0.0)
    glVertex3f(100, 0, 0.0)
    glVertex3f(100, 100, 0.0)
    glVertex3f(0, 100, 0.0)
    glEnd()

def on_draw(): 
    window.clear() 
    draw_square()

from pyglet.window import key
@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
    SHIFT_X_BY = 5.5
    if symbol == key.LEFT:
        glTranslatef(-SHIFT_X_BY, 0.0, 0.0)
    elif symbol == key.RIGHT:
        glTranslatef(SHIFT_X_BY, 0.0, 0.0)
    elif symbol == key.UP:
        glTranslatef(0.0, SHIFT_X_BY, 0.0)
    elif symbol == key.DOWN:
        glTranslatef(0.0, -SHIFT_X_BY, 0.0)

window.on_draw = on_draw
pyglet.app.run()
```

Now, instead of using `glTranslatef` I thought I can just shift the camera. I modified the code to call `gluLookAt` instead:

```
import pyglet 
from pyglet.gl import *

window = pyglet.window.Window(resizable=True)

def draw_square():
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0.0)
    glVertex3f(100, 0, 0.0)
    glVertex3f(100, 100, 0.0)
    glVertex3f(0, 100, 0.0)
    glEnd()

def on_draw(): 
    window.clear() 
    draw_square()


pos = {'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 0}

from pyglet.window import key
@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
    global pos
    SHIFT_X_BY = 5.5
    if symbol == key.LEFT:
        pos['x'] = pos['x'] + SHIFT_X_BY
    elif symbol == key.RIGHT:
        pos['x'] = pos['x'] - SHIFT_X_BY
    elif symbol == key.UP:
        pos['y'] = pos['y'] + SHIFT_X_BY
    elif symbol == key.DOWN:
        pos['y'] = pos['y'] - SHIFT_X_BY

    gluLookAt(pos['x'], pos['y'], pos['z'], 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

window.on_draw = on_draw
pyglet.app.run()
```

However, if I press one of the arrow keys now, the square just disappears. What am I doing wrong with calling `gluLookAt`?

**EDIT** this following `on_draw()` function doesn't work either (I just get a black screen):

```
def on_draw(): 
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluLookAt(pos['x'], pos['y'], pos['z'], 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    draw_square()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gluLookAt takes 3 types of vectors: "eye", "center" and "up".

The eye is where you look from, center where you look at and the up vector is used to tell the cam how it is "opened". Typically you set up to 0,1,0:

gluLookAt(pos['x'], pos['y'], pos['z'], 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, **0.0, 1.0, 0.0**);

http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual/gluLookAt.3G.html

Comment: I changed to code but the square still disappears once I press a direction key.

Comment: Another issue may be, that you never reset the Modelview matrix. It seems like you're calling gluLookAt multiple times, without something like glLoadIdentity()

Comment: if I add `glLoadIdentity()` before the `draw_square` call, then nothing happens.

Comment: I wouldn't add it before draw_square, but before gluLookAt. But I'm really just guessing.

Comment: `glLoadIdentity` after `draw_square` makes the square disappear after a single button press.

Comment: Another guess: Typically you do your translations in one place. Take the gluLookAt and glLoadIdentity up, just before draw_square: glLoadIdentity; gluLookAt; drawSquare;

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any initialization code that sets up a projection matrix? Is modelview your active matrix? David had the right idea about clearing the matrix first with glLoadIdentity (gluLookAt multiplies itself with the current matrix on the stack), but if you haven't switched to modelview matrix then wiping the projection matrix would cause problems.

Comment: no, I don't setup a projection matrix. The code that you see above is all that I do. Which `gl*` commands are missing?

Comment: I did a little research into pyglet and it sets up an orthographic matrix automatically, so I think you can ignore my questions.